# echo html code with php loop

Tags: php, html

in my project i have many  id and every id have number  like p1,p2,p3 ...

```
    </ons-list-item>
    </list-item>
```

so i create php for generate code like

```
<?php
for ($x = 0; $x <= 100; $x++) {
echo " <ons-list-item id="p+$x" onclick="fn.load('s+$x.html');ofsc();"     tappable>

    </ons-list-item>"; 
}
?>
```

for rsult:

```
    <ons-list-item id="p1" onclick="fn.load('s1.html');ofsc();" tappable>

    </ons-list-item>
    <ons-list-item id="p2" onclick="fn.load('s2.html');ofsc();" tappable>

    </ons-list-item>
```

but dont working and display error {Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'p' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in
}

Comment: Did you make typo's in the echo line example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`+` is not a concatenation operator, `.` is. Also, your `for` loop should be like this:

```
for ($x = 1; $x <= 100; $x++) {
    echo "<list-item id='p" . $x . "'></list-item>"; 
}
```

#### Update(1):

```
for ($x = 1; $x <= 100; $x++) {
    ?>
    <ons-list-item id='p<?php echo $x; ?>' onclick="fn.load('s<?php echo $x; ?>.html');ofsc();" tappable>
    </ons-list-item>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: not working and do not  display anything

Comment: @JackKing It won't display anything unless you put *something* in there, like `echo "<list-item id='p" . $x . "'>Something Here</list-item>";`. Do `ctrl+u`(Windows) or `cmd+u`(Mac) to see the source code.

Comment: pleas i want loop for p1 and s1
`  <ons-list-item id="p1" onclick="fn.load('s1.html');ofsc();" tappable>
        </ons-list-item>`

Comment: @JackKing It seems you've kept out critical information from the question. What exactly you're trying to do here?

Comment: sounds like coursework

Comment: The real question I have ` <ons-list-item id="p1" onclick="fn.load('s1.html');ofsc();" tappable> </ons-list-item>`
But here I wrote a section of questions and resolve with id="p1", but does not work with `onclick="fn.load('s1.html');ofsc();" tappable`

Comment: Please look at the question after edited @RajdeepPaul

Comment: @JackKing I've updated my answer. Please see the **Update(1)** section of my answer.

Comment: wow now worked you Worth vote thank you :) @RajdeepPaul

Comment: @JackKing Glad I could help. *Cheers! :-)*

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is:

```
<?php for ($x = 0; $x <= 100; $x++): ?>
   <ons-list-item id="p<?php echo $x ?>" onclick="fn.load(\'s<?php echo $x ?>.html\');ofsc();" tappable></ons-list-item>
<?php endfor; ?>
```

or

```
for ($x = 1; $x <= 100; $x++) {
   echo sprintf('<ons-list-item id="p%s" onclick="fn.load('s%s.html');ofsc();" tappable></ons-list-item>, $x); 
}
```

or

```
for ($x=1; $x <= 100; $x++) {
   echo '<ons-list-item id="p' . $x . '" onclick="fn.load(\'s' . $x . '.html\');ofsc();" tappable></ons-list-item>'; 
}
```

Comment: three code no working sir

Comment: Those are really basic codes and I am sure will work. Can you please show me how you implement it?

Comment: They work for me, you're doing something wrong jack

Comment: i am use windows and xwamp localhost and do not display anything

Comment: Please add following code to top of your php page: `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL); `to see whats going on.

Comment: you can applied your way for the code 
`<ons-list-item id="p1" onclick="fn.load('s1.html');ofsc();" tappable>
        </ons-list-item>`
for s1 and p1

Comment: Well, you should change your question, otherwise it will not fit the answer if I change it.

Comment: Please look at the question after edited @VuralAcar